# compareTo Java - What is this doing?

Tags: java, comparable

Could anyone tell me the logic behind this piece of code?

```
public int compareTo(Holder o) {
    if(o == null) return -1;
    return this.value.compareTo(o.value);
}
```

Comment: Well, how is the return value of `Comparable.compareTo` documented? How does that tally with what's going on here? Which specific part do you not understand?

Comment: You just need to look here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: You can get more details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017381/compareto-method-java

Answer (score 1):

It compares `this` against another object `o`.

If `o` is null, then `this` is considered smaller than `o` (indicated by return value `-1`).

Otherwise the fields `value` of `this` and `o` are compared and the result is returned as comparison result (`-1` = smaller, `1` = greater, `0` = equal).

The rationale is to have a proper ordering of elements, e.g. to sort a list.

Comment: In plain words, it orders `null` after everything else (with everything else in its natural order according to its `.value`).