# How to use CompareTo for sorting alphabet

Tags: java, sorting, oop, compareto

```
package no.hiof.suzdarbi.oblig4;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Film extends Produksjon implements Comparable{

    public Film(String tittel, String beskrivelse, double spilleTid, LocalDate utgivelsesDatoo, Person regissor){
        super(tittel,beskrivelse,spilleTid,utgivelsesDatoo,regissor);
        FilmListe.add(this);
    }


    public static ArrayList<Film> FilmListe = new ArrayList<Film>();
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Film tittel: " + tittel + '\n' +
               "Beskrivelse av filmen: " + beskrivelse + '\n' +
               "Spilletid: " + spilleTid + " minutter" + '\n' +
               "Utgivelsesdato: " + utgivelsesDatoo + '\n' +
               "Regissør: " + regissor.hentNavn() + '\n';
    }    

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Hello, Im currently making a simple Film program, here i want use compareTo to sort my arraylist alphabetically. So Films From A-Z, and I'm not quite sure how to implement this in my compareTo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compareTo method java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017381/compareto-method-java)

Comment: What are you not sure about ? Have you check the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) ? Please [edit] the question to be more specific. See [ask] if needed

Comment: @AxelH I basically want to sort my Films in an alphabetically order using compareTo. In the top you can already see I'm using "Implements Comparable"

Comment: So you have a `Collection` somewhere that you `sort` ? You just need to be able to compare two instance of Film. In general, you can simply compare the variable you want like `this.tittel.compareTo(o.tittel)` (you will need to cast the parameter `o`). Find a short tutorial to try first, then if you are still stuck, I will help you. Check the duplicate question, it will be the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

You need to typecast `object o` to `Film` object. Then you can compare the title of both the films using `String`'s compareTo method.

So `compareTo(Object o)` code would be like this

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Film film = (Film)o;
    return this.title1.compareTo(film.title1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read docs for [Arrays.sort(Object[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])):

From docs:

> Sorts the specified array of objects into ascending order, according
>   to the natural ordering of its elements. All elements in the array
>   must implement the Comparable interface. Furthermore, all elements in
>   the array must be mutually comparable (that is, e1.compareTo(e2) must
>   not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the
>   array).

The sort method does rely on the Comparable interface of the array elements